# JavaFX TableView: collect data from visible columns only

Tags: java, javafx

I want to put the data from a TableView into a Collection of Maps. Each Map represents a row in the table and contains the columnName-entry-pairs of all visible columns.

Now the tricky part for me is to get the data from the visible columns only.

On the TableView, I could call `getItems()`, but how could I then check which column is visible?

With `getColumns()`, I can check which column is visible, but how could I then get the corresponding data?

The easiest thing would be a way to iterate through all visible columns - but I can't find a way to do this.

Can anyone give me a hint or a pointer in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, though I did not test this:

```
final ObservableList<Map<String, Object>> collection = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

tableView.getItems().forEach(item -> {
    final Map<String, Object> itemMap = new HashMap<>();

    tableView.getVisibleLeafColumns().forEach(column -> {
        itemMap.put(column.getText(), column.getCellObservableValue(item).getValue());
    }
    collection.add(itemMap);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This was exactly what I was looking for (especially the "getCellObservableValue"-method). After adjusting it just a little bit to fit into my code, it works perfectly fine! (there were 2 tiny typos in your answer, but they were so tiny I just edited them myself).

Comment: @Tobi Yeah I didn't even type these codes into any code editor lol... Good to know it works.

Comment: That's perfectly fine. I wasn't expecting working code anyway. Telling me about the getCellObservableValue-method would already have made me happy. Getting an almost finished solution is just fantastic:-)